PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 21): Wrap-Up
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 100 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >

This puzzle is also available as a Google sheet.

What you need is

 XMAS PRESCIENCE a little pun on ‘Xmas presents’.

Why?
Completed crossword

 Method: After obtaining the answers and filling the gifts correctly match and wrap the ‘wraps’ answers around the presents in way which formulates five-letter words going down or across…


 

Then

  Take letters in green which is an anagram. After solving the anagram you get the answer above! 
 Thanks to Stiv for spotting how the OP actually wanted the extraction: if we superimpose the grids on top of each other and isolate the green squares reading the remainder anti clockwise we get our answer:
 


Ah, I mistakenly thought that the rot13(ubfcvgny ebbzf jnf REF, fb V jnf jbaqrevat jul ab erfhygf sbe "HPYN YRF" ghearq hc va zl frnepu!)

No need for an anagram even - read anti-clockwise :)

@stiv well spotted!
